# Maven plugins execution order

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

So here is the situation, I want to apply yuicompressor plugin and replacer plugin before war is created. So I need to apply replacer and compress operation on my files after they have been **copied** to target folder. The problem is its(static files jsp/js or other webapps') not getting copied before **package** lifecycle.

**using maven version m2e 3.0.4 so order should work.**

How do I manually copy webapp content before default-war does? And if I copy it somehow will default-war copy it again by overwriting?

What order I want of maven plugins:
1.yuicompressor
2.replacer
3.war

And the pom's plugin order for this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compressor</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compress</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- compressing -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- js/css replacer -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>replace</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <!-- replacing -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But what I get out of package phase:

maven log:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) @ Scheduler ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [Scheduler] in [D:\Development\TFCore\target\Scheduler]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\Development\TFCore\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [24946 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: D:\Development\TFCore\target\Scheduler.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.4.0:compress (compressor) @ Scheduler ---
[INFO] generate aggregation : D:\Development\TFCore\target\Scheduler\scripts\base.js
[INFO] base.js (4368673b)
[INFO] generate aggregation : D:\Development\TFCore\target\Scheduler\styles\base.css
[INFO] base.css (732042b)
[INFO] nb warnings: 0, nb errors: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- replacer:1.5.3:replace (default) @ Scheduler ---
[INFO] Replacement run on 302 files.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default) @ Scheduler ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [Scheduler] in [D:\Development\TFCore\target\Scheduler]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\Development\TFCore\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [22159 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: D:\Development\TFCore\target\Scheduler.war
```

Comment: Can you show us the POM?

Comment: What mvn command you use to run the replacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the maven-war-plugin a second time in your project with a different id (default) in the execution which causes the duplication of the maven-war-plugin execution. Apart from that you can bound the yuicompressor to the prepare-package phase as well as the replacer-plugin. The order of execution of yuicompressor and replacer plugin is given by the order within the pom.xml file.

Comment: @RyanRansford what command is used to run mvn replacer? I get null file does not exists error on running mvn:replace

Comment: @user1610812 You run all non-core maven plug-ins (groupId not like maven-<blah>-plugin) using `mvn <groupId>:<artifactId>`. So in this case, you would use `mvn com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer` to run just the replacer plugin.

Comment: @RyanRansford using mvn com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer I get no Plugin found in the plugins group But I am using         groupId:artifactId:replace and I get File:C:\users\repoDir\null does not exist. Replace run on 0 files.

Comment: @user1610812, I believe that you'd be better off starting your own question and posting relevant sections of your `pom.xml` and `settings.xml`.